# Code for generating all unique permutations recursively?

Tags: python, permutation

Say I have a list `L=[1,2,3,3,4]` and I want to find all permutations of length 3 recursively.

I am trying to return all unique permutations, which means something like `[1,2,3]` isn't included in the output twice because there are two `3`'s in `L`.

I ask because itertools.permutations includes duplicates, and also I am trying to iterate through the permutations in order (iterating from the lowest `[1,2,3]` up to `[4,3,3]`) because I want to be able to quit iterating whenever I need to.

I'm sorry if I haven't explained things properly.

Edit: I should probably elaborate again. In practice, I don't want to actually generate every single possible permutation (there would be way too many), although the code could if it ran to completion. I'm trying to iterate through all the permutations in a particular order so that I can bail early if necessary.

Comment: You want to avoid duplicating `[1, 2, 3]`, but you also want to include `[4, 3, 3]` in the output? Perhaps that's possible, but it seems inconsistent to me...

Comment: @senderle Well [1,2,3] might duplicate with another [1,2,3]. [4,3,3] is still a valid permutation in itself.

Comment: Yes, but in one case you're treating `3`s as identical, and in the other case, you're treating them as distinct. It's not hard to do a post-hoc filter, but I'm having a difficult time seeing how you could generate _only_ the values you want. How would you tell when to treat `3`s as identical, and when to treat them as distinct? Again, perhaps it's possible, but I'm not sure the benefit outweighs the increase in complexity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
l = [1,2,3,3,4]

print sorted(set(itertools.permutations(l,3)))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 2), (1, 3, 3), (1, 3, 4), ..., (4, 3, 3)]
```

This keeps it in order and removes duplicates.

---

If you want to avoid generating each possible permutation before-hand, I would do something like this:

```
gen = itertools.permutations(l,3)
s = set()

for i in gen:
    if i not in s:
        print i  # or do anything else
    # if some_cond: break
    s.add(i)
```

Here `gen` is a *generator*, so you are not pre-creating all of the elements you might use.

Comment: This doesn't allow me to iterate through on the fly and bail out of a subloop when I need to, though. I am looking for a recursive type of approach if possible.

Comment: @johnsmith - I think you need to clarify what conditions you intend to 'bail out' on.

Comment: @JohnSmith Why can you not iterate through? Also, I would strongly suggest not reinventing the wheel and using `itertools` if at all possible (since it's made/optimized for exactly this).

Comment: @Aesthete Each permutation is being used as an argument in another function, but if [1,2,3] won't work, then neither will [1,2,4] or [1,2,5] or [1,2,6], etc, so I bail early and start with [1,3,2] or something to that effect. Itertools doesn't allow me to do what I want here, especially since it uses duplicates.

Comment: I feel badly about all this and suspect it's too complex a problem to discuss in this format. I'm just going to accept this as the answer, sorry for wasting your time. I'll have to think more on this.

Comment: +1, since I can't conceive a better approach to the problem than the second post-hoc filter. It will start to burn up a lot of memory though! Personally, without a strong argument against it, I'd just put up with a few duplicates and just use the output of `itertools.permutations` directly.