# how to quickly count equal element in a numpy.array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a python matrix

```
leafs = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[2,3,4],[4,2,1]])
```

I would like to compute for each couple of rows the number of time they have the same element.

In this case I would get a 4x4 matrix proximity

```
proximity = array([[3, 2, 0, 1],
                   [2, 3, 1, 1],
                   [0, 1, 3, 0],
                   [1, 1, 0, 3]])
```

This is the code that I am currently using.

```
proximity = []

for i in range(n):
 print(i)
 proximity.append(np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: sum(x==leafs[i, :]), axis=1,
                                      arr=leafs))
```

I need a faster solution

EDIT: 
The accepted solution does not work in this example

```
    >>> type(f.leafs)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> f.leafs.shape
(7210, 1000)
>>> f.leafs.dtype
dtype('int64')

>>> f.leafs.reshape(7210, 1, 1000) == f.leafs.reshape(1, 7210, 1000)
False
>>> f.leafs
array([[ 19,  32,  16, ..., 143, 194, 157],
       [ 19,  32,  16, ..., 143, 194, 157],
       [ 19,  32,  16, ..., 143, 194, 157],
       ..., 
       [139,  32,  16, ...,   5, 194, 157],
       [170,  32,  16, ...,   5, 194, 157],
       [170,  32,  16, ...,   5, 194, 157]])
>>>
```

Comment: Itertools ([python2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) | [python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)) should have something..? Try investigating this answer for [Generate all unique permutations of 2d array](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21960058/1762224)

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise about what your output should be?  Maybe I'm tired but for 'each couple of rows' I'm not seeing how a 4x3 maps to a 4x4

Comment: The final matrix is squared and has the same number of rows of the initial one. Each row of the matrix is compared with all the others. `similarity[i,j] = sum(leafs[i,k] == leafs[j,k] for k in range(len(leafs[i,:]))'

Comment: What are the elements on the array? Integers, strings, floats?

Comment: The elements are integers.

Comment: How big are the actual arrays?

Comment: 4000 rows and 100 or 1000 columns

Comment: How many distinct integers do you expect to have in your array? Are they all quite different, or there are some categories?

Comment: Edit suggestion: Instead of "for each couple of rows", it would be clearer to say "for each pair of rows".

Comment: Strange.  If `l1` and `l2` are normal numpy arrays of integers, `l1 == l2` should return an *array*, not `False`.  If the result is too big, it should raise a `MemoryError` exception.  Could you also show `l1.dtype` and `l2.dtype`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warren Weckesser offered a very beautiful solution using broadcasting. However, even a straightforward approach using a loop can have comparable performance. `np.apply_along_axis` is slow in your initial solution because it does not take advantage of vectorization. However the following fixes it:

```
def proximity_1(leafs):
    n = len(leafs)
    proximity = np.zeros((n,n))
    for i in range(n):
        proximity[i] = (leafs == leafs[i]).sum(1)  
    return proximity
```

You could also use a list comprehension to make the above code more concise. The difference is that `np.apply_along_axis` would loop through all the rows in a non-optimized manner, while `leafs == leafs[i]` will take advantage of `numpy` speed.

The solution from Warren Weckesser truly shows `numpy`'s beauty. However, it includes the overhead of creating an intermediate 3-d array of size `nrows*nrows*ncols`. So if you have large data, the simple loop might be more efficient.

Here's an example. Below is code offered by Warren Weckesser, wrapped in a function. (I don't know what are the code copyright rules here, so I assume this reference is enough `:)`)

```
def proximity_2(leafs):
    nrows, ncols = leafs.shape    
    eq = leafs.reshape(nrows,1,ncols) == leafs.reshape(1,nrows,ncols)
    proximity = eq.sum(axis=-1)  
    return proximity
```

Now let's evaluate the performance on an array of random integers of size 10000 x 100.

```
leafs = np.random.randint(1,100,(10000,100))
time proximity_1(leafs)
>> 28.6 s
time proximity_2(leafs) 
>> 35.4 s
```

I ran both examples in an `IPython` environment on the same machine.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way, using broadcasting.  Be warned: the temporary array `eq` has shape `(nrows, nrows, ncols)`, so if `nrows` is 4000 and `ncols` is 1000, `eq` will require 16GB of memory.

```
In [38]: leafs
Out[38]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 4],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [4, 2, 1]])

In [39]: nrows, ncols = leafs.shape

In [40]: eq = leafs.reshape(nrows,1,ncols) == leafs.reshape(1,nrows,ncols)

In [41]: proximity = eq.sum(axis=-1)

In [42]: proximity
Out[42]: 
array([[3, 2, 0, 1],
       [2, 3, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 3, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 3]])
```

Also note that this solution is inefficient: `proximity` is symmetric, and the diagonal is always equal to `ncols`, but this solution computes the full array, so it does more than twice as much work as necessary.

Comment: This is a fantastic solution and it is very very fast! Can you explain command 40 and 41 .  Thanks!

Comment: @Donbeo, 4x1x3 against 1x4x3 => 4x4x3. [doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

Comment: @Warren Weckesser There is a case in which your solution does not work. I have edited the question. This can probably be due to an excessive use of memory

Comment: As I noted in my answer, I expected memory would be an issue if the the dimensions of `leafs` were large.  Broadcasting+reduction is handy, but the the excessive memory use of intermediate results can be an issue.  @ojy's answer is a reasonable way to break up the calculation into small steps.

Comment: I have edited the question. I am just curious to know why this is not working. The ojy answer is probably better in my situation